# Why "ios::sync_with_studio(0) and cin.tie(0);" doesn't work with strings in C++

Tags: c++, c++17, stdio

I was solving one problem using C++ where I have to take a **string** as an input. So instead of using the standard input/output method, I tried to use fast input/output method.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_studio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
 
    string str;
    cin>>str;
    cout<<str;
    return 0;
}
```

it shows an error:-

```
error: 'sync_with_studio' is not a member of 'std::ios {aka std::basic_ios<char>}'
     ios::sync_with_studio(0);
     ^~~
```

but if I use

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
```

it worked.
can someone tell why the above code doesn't work and why this work

Comment: Why do you expect it to work with `ios::sync_with_studio(0);` (missing `_base`)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with strings.

Comment: "_`studio`_"? What's that?

Comment: Also, it is `stdio` not `studio` (`stdio` stands for "standard input/output")

Comment: my bad, I didn't check the syntax.

Comment: Just forget about this line of code, as well as about `typedef long long ll;`. Bear in mind that the only thing "coding websites" will teach you is how to write really bad and unmaintainable code. This has nothing to do with professional programming.

Comment: Please don't edit answers into the question, it's very confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way it is. You need to make sure that you're writing the names correctly. You can always take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/.

But in this case, check this: [std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)

Also keep in mind that if set to false, the C++ standard stream objects such as `cout`, `clog`, `cerr`, `wcout`, etc. will not be synchronized and you might see unexpectedly interleaved output if you mix them.

Answer (score 1):

you made a syntax error, there
The function

```cpp
static bool sync_with_stdio( bool sync = true );
```

Sets whether the standard C++ streams are synchronized to the standard C streams after each input/output operation.

By default, all eight standard C++ streams are synchronized with their respective C streams. As, synchronized C++ streams are guaranteed to be thread-safe (individual characters output from multiple threads may interleave, but no data races occur).

But while doing competitive programming, people usually care about faster code execution, rather than quality and safety. Thus when the synchronization is turned off, the C++ standard streams are allowed to buffer their I/O independently allowing faster executions.

Comment: Note that using an incorrect function name isn't really a syntax error, syntax errors are where you violate the syntax of the language (e.g missing a semicolon on it end of a line)

Answer (score 0):

ios::sync_with_stdio does not accept int that you tried

wrong : `ios::sync_with_stdio(0)`

right : `ios::sync_with_stdio() or ios::sync_with_stdio(false)`

Default is true.

Please see the function definition is xiosbase.